# Is there any opensource high-performance IPC-like msg bus library in c++?

Tags: c++, ipc

In my current project, I have a slightly distributed architecture, i.e., several executables collaborate with each other to get things done. To make things easier, i hope i could have a reliable 'backbone' message bus: when an executable hooks up to the msg bus, it can receive callback when new msg arrives. Similarly, it can publish new message to the bus.

I know some companies provide off-the-shelf solutions like this, however, is there any free ones in the OSS?

Comment: What enviroment and use-case is that for? And what does *slightly* distributed mean?

Comment: basically, there are 2 exe, one is a data publisher, the other is receiver. however, what makes things a little more complicated is that, inside the receiver there need to be also a msg bus, so that one object can publish data/signals to other objects. 

i prefer to use one single msg bus for both these 2 usecases rather than having 2 of them.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need Windows support, and your processes aren't spread over different computers, I'd definately give [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) a look.

It's written in C and features (according to the web page) bindings for "Qt, GLib, Java, C#, Python, etc.)".

The [list of projects using D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DbusProjects) is quite impressive, too.

Comment: I don't recall D-Bus as being high-performance... or did something change drastically in the last year?

Comment: it also seems that WinDbus, the windows port is lagging behind which is why I never tried to integrated D-Bus in my developments

Answer (score 3):

Have you given a thought to using AMQP based like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com)?

There are some libraries for `C` [binding](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/) you could "dress-up" for C++.

> RabbitMQ is a complete and highly
>   reliable enterprise messaging system
>   based on the emerging AMQP
>   standard. It is licensed under the
>   open source Mozilla Public License and
>   has a platform-neutral distribution,
>   plus platform-specific packages and
>   bundles for easy installation.

---

Of course, if you require something "less-distributed" you could go straight to using DBus.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the given answers, [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess.html#interprocess.intro) should be a portable and performant alternative.
If you're really looking for high performance though, scrap the idea of using the IPC library for in-process-communication too - there will be performance penalties.

Comment: Scrapping in favor of shared memory?

Comment: That was about in-process-communication, no shared memory or other IPC mechanisms needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the AMQP idea above, you might want to look at ZeroMQ (http://www.zeromq.org/).  I haven't used it personally, but I know people who like it a lot.